# Understanding pointers in specific code sample

Tags: c, list, pointers

The following bit of code in C is supposed to append a number at the end of a list. We have the following struct for the list:

```
struct element
{
   int value;
   struct element *next;
};
```

And the following code for the Append function:

```
void append (struct element **l, int value)
{
   struct element *tmp = *l;
   struct element *new = (struct element *) malloc (sizeof (struct element));
   new->value = value;
   new->next = NULL;

   if (tmp == NULL)
   *l = new;
   else
   {
      while (tmp->next != NULL)
      {
          tmp = tmp->next;
      }
      tmp->next = new;
   }
}
```

I don't understand the use of pointers in the code above, in particular, I have no clue why l appears sometimes with two asterisks, and sometimes with one, and why tmp appears sometimes with an asterisk and sometimes without. I also don't understand where the asterisk appears as a dereferencing operator and where it serves for defining pointers. I have read an introduction to pointers in C but couldn't wrap my mind around pointers in this code anyway. Help appreciated.

Comment: "I also don't understand where the asterisk appears as a dereferencing operator and where it serves for defining pointers." -- Apparently you *do* understand the difference.

Comment: I understand the difference in theory, but I have never really understood how they are used in practice. There is just something very strange in the idea of pointers. Another thing is that most explanations of pointers I have found are written in a language which is inaccessible to people who are not programmers.

Comment: Non-programmers become programmers all the time, so the claim that the explanations are "inaccessible" is nonsense. If you already understand that sometimes `*` is a dereferencing operator and sometimes it is used to define a pointer, then all you need to do is learn the syntax rules for those two cases. There is vast amounts of highly accessible explanations.

Comment: Also, there's really nothing strange about pointers, as we use the concept all the time when we deal with names, addresses, words in general. Think of a pointer as a piece of paper on which is written a number which represents one of several numbered boxes. Boxes can contain various things such as ints or structs ... or other pointers (pieces of paper). `struct element **l` declares `l` to be a pointer to a box that contains a pointer to a box that contains a `struct element`. You don't have to be a programmer to understand that.

Comment: Among the highly accessible explanations of C is the original by its inventors: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0131103628/?tag=stackoverfl08-20 ... if people were required to read this before asking C questions at SO, there would be far fewer of such questions and they would be much higher quality.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is a variable which holds a memory address. A double pointer is a variable which holds a memory address which address also holds a memory address. This is commonly used for lists and multi-dimensional arrays.

Unless it's the initial declaration, the asterisk is a *dereferencing operator* which means that instead of accessing the memory address, it's accessing the value stored in the memory address.

[Check this out.](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is basic C, but...

1. The declaration of `l` is `struct element **l`.  The way C works means that `**l` refers to something of type `struct element`, so `*l` refers to something that is of type `struct element *` (a pointer to a `struct element`) and plain `l` refers to a `struct element **` (a pointer to a pointer to a `struct element`).
2. Similarly, the declaration of `tmp` is `struct element *tmp` so `*tmp` is a `struct element`, and `tmp` is a pointer to `struct element`.

The pointer to pointer is necessary so that if the new element is the head of the list, then the head of the list in the calling function can be updated.  The assignment to `*l` ensures that the variable in the calling function is updated.

Comment: But if tmp is a pointer to struct element, rather than a struct element, how can an expression like tmp->next make sense?

Comment: @Balerion_the_black `tmp.next` means "access the `next` variable in the structure tmp." `tmp->next` means "access the `next` variable in the structure that the pointer named tmp is pointing to."

Comment: @ciphermagi Ah I see...makes sense. One more question. What exactly does the declaration "struct element *tmp = *l;" mean? Does it mean that tmp is a pointer pointing to...the pointer pointing to l?

Comment: @Balerion_the_black No, it's making the (single) pointer named tmp equal the (dereferenced one time) (double) pointer named l. So it's declaring a single pointer and setting it to the value in the double pointer, which value is itself a single pointer.

Comment: @Balerion_the_black It achieves the same result as `"struct element *tmp; tmp = *l;` -- the first part defines `tmp` to be a pointer to a `struct element` and the second part (the initializer, `= ...` within a definition) sets `tmp` to the value pointed to by `l`.

Comment: @Balerion_the_black: Note that `tmp->next` is a shorthand for `(*tmp).next` (literally), so `(*tmp)` is a `struct element` and `.next` refers to a component of that element. Using `->` means that the left-hand expression must be of type `pointer to struct element` (for some structure type); it cannot be of type `struct element`, nor can it be of type pointer to pointer to `struct element`.

Comment: @Balerion_the_black "how can an expression like tmp->next make sense" -- because it's shorthand for `(*tmp).next`. The real question is, what sort of misunderstanding is behind thinking that it doesn't (or can't, yet) make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of a pointer is always with a * to mark it as pointer.
If you want normal variables, you´ll make `int i;` or `struct element e;`,
and pointer to int/elements would be `int *pi;` or `struct element *pe;`.

With a normal variable i, you can get the value with `i` and the address with `&i`.
A pointer is "just" an variable to hold an address, ie. a variable holding a number,
so you can get the saved address with `pi` (and, if nessecary,
the address of the pointer variable itself with `&pi`).
What a pointer can do additionally: `*pi` to get the value
of the thing which is at the saved address.

Two asterisks is a pointer to a pointer (to some variable).
Ie- there is a pointer who´s saved address is the address of pointer b,
and b has the address of variable c in it.

Why pointers are useful with function parameters:
Suppose, you have a variable i in main and you are passing i as parameter to function f.
Everything is ok so far, but: If you want to chanage i in f, it won´t be persistent,
ie. when f ends, the value of the variable in main
will be the same as before, without change.
Why? Because, when passing a parameter, a *copy* is passed.
The function will only change the copy (which will be deleted again after f ends).

If you take a pointer instead of the variable itself and pass the address of i,
just the addres number will be copied. But both addresses still points to
the same variable, so now you can change it.

And if you have a pointer in main and want to pass it to a function
which should not only change to thing it points to,
but the address in the pointer as well?
->You´ll need a pointer to the pointer...

Answer (score 1):

The two above answers are quite comprehensive, I just add two comments.

1. Multiple asterisks. Don't feel confused about multiple asterisks. It just means the pointer to a variable, which the variable is a pointer itself. For example:

   int a = 10;

   int* p = &a;

   int** q = &p;

   int***r = &q;

   printf("%d", ***r);

   it will output 10.
2. When adding *, when not. In fact, the declare of "int* p" and "int *p" are the same while I prefer the former. Then p means the pointer (an address), *p means the content it points to.

Comment: I don't think this will compile in C. Pretty sure C can't handle `std::cout`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I should change it to printf.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten pretty good answers already, I'd add a strong personal recommendation for [The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) by Kernighan and Ritchie (K&R).  The chapter on pointers will clear this up for you nicely.

Comment: K&R is an excellent but slightly dated book.  It is a model for succinctness, but it describes the 1989 standard C, and also a bit of the Unix environment circa 1988.  There have been two updates to the C standard, and Unix has been standardized (POSIX) and some of the examples no longer work -- when was the last time you saw an old-style Unix file system with file names limited to 14 bytes? It is also not really a book to learn programming from; it is a book to learn how to program in C given that you already know how to program (in some other imperative programming language).